# Ext4 Samba Share reports wrong disk size

Tags: backup, samba, disk-usage, deja-dup

I have a 1.7TB primary partition formatted to ext4 that is currently being shared via samba from my raspberry pi. My goal was to use this partition with Ubuntu's built in Deja-Dup backup utility. However, upon performing the first backup and pointing to my samba share, Deja-Dup errors out complaining that the there is not enough free space on the share. Here is the output of `df -h` on the pi:

`/dev/sdb3       1.7T  4.0G  1.6T   1% /media/SG_MEDIA`

Clearly there is enough space. However, when I connect to the share via nautilus's "Connect to Server" in the sidebar, right click in the window, and select properties, it reports only 3GB of free space as seen here:

[image: Nautilus]

Clearly, this is not accurate. Anyone have any ideas of what is causing this? In my smb.conf file I have explicitly set `max disk size = 0` and the problem persists. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, this is what caused the issue:

I was sharing my root directory via samba and attempting to navigate through it to create the backup, i.e., backing up to smb://192.168.1.2/root/media/SG_MEDIA. This was what reported the 3GB free space.

However, when I directly shared my connected HD, i.e., creating a samba share directly to /media/SG_MEDIA and backing up to smb://192.168.1.2/SG_MEDIA it reported the correct space. Can't say why.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm looks like each file is round-up to nearly 1MB.

Here is an workaround:

1. Edit smb.conf and add this:

   [global]

   allocation roundup size = 4096
2. Restart samba.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this one didn't seem to work for my situation. I did find an answer below though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different mount points under a single Samba share, you can use the `dfree command` setting in the share's definition to point to a custom script which will decide how to advertise the total and free space of the share to clients.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#idm2868) is not quite correct as of May 2023. But there is a [detailed explanation in my answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/1131133/63361).

In the script, you can use `$PWD` to decide which numbers to report.

This is the script I use, also shown in the linked answer above:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

diskA="$PWD/disk1"
diskB="$PWD/disk2"

# get total number of blocks and free blocks
# into arrays sizesA and sizesB
sizesA=( $( df $diskA | tail -1 | awk '{print $2,$4}' ) )
sizesB=( $( df $diskB | tail -1 | awk '{print $2,$4}' ) )

# return sizes of the disk with smaller free space left
if (( ${sizesA[1]} <= ${sizesB[1]} )); then
    echo "${sizesA[@]}"
else
    echo "${sizesB[@]}"
fi
```